# call method async with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

The example below :
Why when i called the function fct1 with the arguments i lose async between functions.
The execution of the function is the order: fct3,fct2,fct1 instead fct1,fct2,fct3

```
function fct1(param1) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("fct1 : param1 =" + param1);
      d.resolve();
    }, 3000);
  return d.promise();
};


function fct2() {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("fct2");
      d.resolve();
    }, 2000);
  return d.promise();
};

function fct3() {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("fct3");
      d.resolve();
    }, 1000);
  return d.promise();
};


var fct_array = [fct1(1), fct2, fct3];

var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
while (fct_array.length > 0) {
  d = d.then(fct_array.shift());
}
```

Comment: It's "async" not "sync", that means that the first is the faster ... fct3 is 1000 fct2 is 2000 fct3 is 3000 so everything works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe that because of timeout

Comment: I want to execute those functions in order (fct1, fct2, fct3) with parameters, i don't know why when i add the parameter for function fc1 i lose sync between function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your fctl() function definition as:

```
function fct1(param){

  var p =param;
  var f = function(p){  
      var d = $.Deferred();
      setTimeout(function() {
              console.log("fct1 : p=" + p);
          d.resolve();
        }, 5000);
      return d.promise();
  }

  return f.bind(this,p);
};
```

reason being that before you where executing the function `fctl(1)` when you were initializing the array `fct_array`. Thus later one calling `.then` it did was already resolved.

**Note:** No need to change the while loop as you are reinitializing the object d as `d=d.then(fct_array.shift());`
Thus,

```
while (fct_array.length > 0) {
  d = d.then(fct_array.shift());
}

/* is equal to :
d=d.then(fct_array.shift()).then(fct_array.shift()).then(fct_array.shift());
*/
```

**Implementation**: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gelijo/22/edit?js,console)

Comment: My question how i can for example call fct1 with parameter without lose sync between functions ? I test your response i lose sync !!!

Comment: while loop is fine, simply change the fctl(param) function definition.

Comment: I tested your solution unfortunately it doesn't work.
i think because in function i make ( return d.promise(); )
do you have any suggestions ?